# Does $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^p) $ imply $ f(\cdot , x) \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{p-1})$?(answered)

Tags: real-analysis

Does $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^p)$ imply $f(.,x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{p-1})$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Thompson's answer: No;

A Blumenthal's answer: $f(.,x)\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^{p-1})$ for a.e. $x\in\mathbb{R}$ up to lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no.

If you have defined your Lebesgue spaces by identifying functions that agree almost everywhere, then it does not make sense to restrict a fixed function to a subspace like this.

Otherwise, i.e. in the case that the question does make sense, the answer is no: Let $f(x,y) = 0$ if $y \neq 0$ and $f(x,y) = 1/x$ if $y = 0$.

Now $f = 0$ Lebesgue - almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so certainly $\int |f|^2 d\mathcal{L}^2 < \infty$, i.e. $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

However the function $x \mapsto f(x,0) = 1/x$ does not belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R}))$

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $p = 2$ for simplicity. By Tonelli's theorem,

$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x, y)|^2 dx dy = \int_{y = -\infty}^\infty \bigg( \int_{x = - \infty}^\infty |f(x,y)|^2 dx \bigg) dy \,.
$$
Your hypotheses claim that the left-hand side is finite. So, the parenthetical integrand on the right-hand side must be finite almost-surely. Do you see how to conclude $f(\cdot, y) \in L^2$ for Lebesgue-almost every $y \in \mathbb R$?